# Haskell: Verify that every implementation for a function in a typeclass is commutative

Tags: haskell, testing, properties

Suppose we have a function f :: (T a) => a -> a -> a -> in a typeclass T, typeclass which has instances in numerous types.
Suppose we want this function to be commutative regardless of its implementation for a given type, i. e.
`∀ a, b ∈ X: (T X, Eq X) => ∃ f X -> X -> X,  f a b == f b a`
If I were to verify commutativity for a more concrete case, let`s say (+) and Int, I could write something like this:

```
import Test.Quickcheck (quickCheck)

commutativityProperty :: Eq a => (a -> a -> a) -> a -> a -> Bool
commutativityProperty f a b = f a b == f b a

main :: IO ()
main = do
  quickCheck (commutativityProperty (+) :: Int -> Int -> Bool)
```

quickCheck does not work with ambiguous type variables, so I could not write something like this:
`quickCheck (commutativityProperty (+) :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> a -> Bool)`
Or, for the more general case:
`quickCheck (commutativityProperty f :: (T a, Eq a) => a -> a -> Bool)`
The **Question** is:
In a similar context, where I know this function must hold commutativity regardless of implementation for a specific type, how can I verify that this is indeed true without having to write a line of quickCheck for every type that implements f and have to maintain that code (i.e. every time a new type with an instance of T is created, I would have to come back and write a new line for that specific type)?

Comment: I think it's pretty common to have to write a new test when you write new code, generally. If that's the outcome you arrive at, I am not sure you should worry about that fact too much.

Comment: Typeclasses are open, so anyone can come along and define a new instance which your test suite program has never seen. If you're okay with this and want to test types that you know about specifically (i.e. types whose `T` instances you can explicitly bring into scope by importing them) then you get get a hold of all the instances using [template-haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.18.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v:reifyInstances).

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches come to mind:

## Generate random types

Using GADTs, you could try to generate a "random type" and use that for testing your polymorphic function. This is not entirely easy, but it could be still feasible depending on your typeclass.

To give you a very rough sketch:

```
data Ty t where
    TInt :: Ty Int
    TPair :: Ty a -> Ty b -> Ty (a,b)

data SomeType where
    ST :: Ty t -> SomeType

test :: SomeType -> (forall a . (T a) => a -> a -> a) -> Bool
test (ST TInt) f = f 4 2  -- actually, these should be generated randomly
test (ST (TPair x y)) f = ...
```

## Testing non-integer types might come for free!

Every time we have a (terminating) polymorphic function, we know it satisfies a property called [*free theorem*](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/wadler/topics/parametricity.html) (the slogan is "theorems for free!"). E.g. if we have `f :: a->a` it has to be the identity, while `g :: a->a->a` has to be `\x y->x` or `\x y->y`. Adding a typeclass constraint like your `T a` makes it more complex, but a free theorem can still be generated.

It is likely that, using such a free theorem, you can prove that if your property hold for integers it has to hold for any type in class `T`. I'll give you an example.

Assume `f :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]` correctly sorts integers. Then, by the free theorem, it also sorts any other totally ordered type. Intuitively, this is because `f` can not really inspect the elements of the input list except using comparisons (`<`, `compare`,...). Hence, if you replace the list elements with suitable integers that have exactly the same comparison results, `f` must perform the "same" operation on both lists.

It is possible that you can play the same trick depending on what your `T` class actually allows.

Answer (score 0):

The typeclass comes with a set of laws which should be fulfilled by each implementation. Whenever you add a new implementation you will have to add tests that make sure that your implementation is correct.

For writing those tests easier you may use libraries like https://hackage.haskell.org/package/quickcheck-classes but, eventually, you will have to write some code that tests the laws of typeclass against your implementation.